# Detect FlowDocument Change and Scroll

Tags: wpf, scroll, flowdocument

I want to detect (preferably through an event) when any content is added, changed, etc. in a `FlowDocument` and when it does I want to cause a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` displaying the `FlowDocument` to automatically scroll to the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can detect changes in the `FlowDocument` by creating a text range and monitoring it for changes.  Scrolling to the bottom is more difficult because you have to find the `ScrollViewer`.  Also for performance you don't want redo all the scrolling calculations on every change, so you should use `DispatcherOperations`.

Putting it all together, this code should do the trick:

```
var range = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
object operation = null;

range.Changed += (obj, e) =>
{
  if(operation==null)
    operation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
    {
      operation = null;

      var scrollViewer = FindFirstVisualDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>(flowDocument);
      scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
    });
};
```

where `FindFirstVisualDescendantOfType` is a simple depth-first prefix search of the visual tree using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` and returning the first Visual found of the specified type.

Note that for full generality I don't precompute scrollViewer at the top of the code because the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`'s template can change.  If this won't happen, this code can be speeded up by calling `.ApplyTemplate()` on the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` and then computing `scrollViewer` before the event handler is registered:

```
var range = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
object operation = null;

flowDocument.ApplyTemplate();
var scrollViewer = FindFirstVisualDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>(flowDocument);

range.Changed += (obj, e) =>
{
  if(operation==null)
    operation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
    {
      operation = null;
      scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
    });
};
```

Note that we cannot simply call `scrollViewer.GetTemplateChild("PART_ContentHost")` and skip the visual tree search because `GetTemplateChild` is protected.

Comment: I did not need any of this with FlowDocument and FlowDocumentScrollViewer visual tree code. Just 2 Invokes, 1 to create and add the paragraph from a string and 1 to bring that paragraph into view.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a RichTextBox to do the editing? If so you should just be able to hook [the `TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) and then call [the `ScrollToVerticalOffset` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx) with the value from [the `ViewportHeight` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.viewportheight.aspx).

Comment: No. Using FlowDocumentScrollViewer, not RichTextBox.

Answer (score 2):

After hooking up to a TextChanged Event, you can simply use:

```
// Showing Last Block
YourReader.Document.Blocks.LastBlock.BringIntoView();

// Or.. showing the last Inline
(YourReader.Document.Blocks.LastBlock as Paragraph).Inlines.LastInline.BringIntoView();
```

***But,*** this works ***only*** on a FlowDocumentPageViewer, 
and also on a FlowDocumentReader (with pages ViewingModes), for a FlowDocumentScrollViewer
you should use the visual tree as mentioned

```
public static ScrollViewer FindScroll(Visual visual)
        {
            if (visual is ScrollViewer)
                return visual as ScrollViewer;

            ScrollViewer searchChiled = null;
            DependencyObject chiled;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
            {
                chiled = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
                if (chiled is Visual)
                    searchChiled = FindScroll(chiled as Visual);
                if (searchChiled != null)
                    return searchChiled;
            }

            return null;
        }

ScrollViewer scroller = FindScroll(YourReader as Visual);
if (scroller != null) 
   (scroller as ScrollViewer).ScrollToBottom();
```

Comment: I am using only a FlowDocument and FlowDocumentscrollViewer. The BringIntoView solution above works perfectly for me. I did not need VisualTreeHelper

My solution is to use Dispatcher.Invoke to write create the paragraph, store that paragraph as a variable and then Dispatcher.Invoke again to bring it into view. 

This seems the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method to get the inner scroll viewer:

```
public static class FlowDocumentScrollViewerExtensions
{
  public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(this FlowDocumentScrollViewer element) {
    if (element == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
    }

    return element.Template?.FindName("PART_ContentHost", element) as ScrollViewer;
  }
}
```

Additionally you can use these extension methods before adding content to check the scroll position the scrollviewer itself (in case you want to scroll -only- if the scroll viewer was already at the end for example):

```
public static class ScrollViewerExtensions
{
  public static bool IsAtHome(this ScrollViewer element) {
    if (element == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
    }

    return element.VerticalOffset <= 0;
  }

  public static bool IsAtEnd(this ScrollViewer element) {
    if (element == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
    }

    return element.VerticalOffset >= element.ScrollableHeight;
  }
}
```

Afterwards just call scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd() for example.